# Can I take The Castle without doing the quest?

Tags: fallout-4

I have recently started Fallout 4, but I am kind of stuck.

The main thing that I was curious about was settlements, however I didn't want a bad one so I went for the castle directly (at lvl 12, great struggle btw).

After killing the Mirelurk Queen, I found out that it was actually a quest I should do for Preston. I can already build in The Castle now, but I didn't do the quest.

The only problem now is that I have 0 settlers and in every video and guide I look they start with 1 or more?

I can't launch the radio tower (which you normally do in the quest?), because you need a settler for that.

I am wondering if I have to do all those quests now in order for me to finally build some nice stuff, I can't because it appears I need settlers to clean this up before I can make something decent.

Also, I can't find Preston in the museum. Where is he?

I did the first 2 quests, but now I have to help 3 settlements before he approaches me? Are these settlements of my own? Do I need to make 3 settlements first?

Comment: I'm pretty confused by your last few sentences. Can you clarify what Minutemen quests you've done, if any? Did you save Preston in Concord? Did you meet up with them at Sanctuary?

Comment: These will be settlements of your own however nothing obliges you to do anything in them. They just need to join the Minuteman, and you can forget about their existence entirely. You could even scrap everything and take all the resources before you leave.

Answer (score 7):

I ended up doing the same thing, if you get the castle before Preston offers you the quest, it won't have any impact on the minutemen questline until you get to the point where he offers the 'retake the castle' (I believe you need to complete three or four settlement recruitment quests for him)at this point you get the speech option to say somthing to the effect of "i've already cleared that place out" and you automatically skip to the second stage of that quest, where you need to build enough generators to power the radio antenna at the castle. After that the minutemen quests proceed as usual. It actually saves time doing it the way you have.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say grab the material you need for a normal radio tower and generator and build it in the castle and wait until you get a settler for the "big" tower.

Comment: Did you test that solution? Will the Minuteman radio work as usual without the quest being completed? Will DCR announce that minuteman have the castle back?

Comment: @Deltharis No, not tried it - just an educated guess.

Comment: This seems like a reasonable suggestion, but it's not really an answer.

Comment: @DCShannon It is if I'm right :-D

Answer (score -3):

I had a similar problem, except Preston would never let me start the mission, well I finally figured out why *faceplams* don't put Preston in the castle until after he gives you the quest (as in don't send him there when he is not your companion) it's easy to fix though, just send him back to a different settlement and then talk to him there, the quest will start right up from there, and if you are like me, it will probably be the last new settlement quest from him in a sense as in repeats

Comment: Welcome to gaming stackexchange. Please note that this website is a bit more formal than usual discussion forums. When you post an answer here, you are expected to only answer the question which was asked, nothing more and nothing less. Your answer addresses a related but different problem, so it isn't an answer to the question that was asked.